# VirtualBox "Kernel driver not installed" error despite running /sbin/vboxconfig

Tags: 14.04, kernel, virtualbox, dkms

When starting a VirtualBox VM, I get:

[image: VirtualBox - Error in suplibOsInit]

Running `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` does not fix the problem.
How to fix that?

*VirtualBox 5.0.10 r104061*

Comment: For me the fix was installing the latest version of virtualbox. (Received error on 6.1.12. Upgraded to 6.1.34). sudo dpkg -i <downloaded file.deb>

Answer (score 13):

same problem with me, 
abort it if you not use vagrant.

the output when i run `vagrant up`:

```
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` or open the VirtualBox GUI to see the error
message which should contain instructions on how to fix this error.
```

output `VBoxManage --version`:

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (3.19.0-47-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.0.14r105127
```

output `sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup`:

```
Bad argument setup
```

My problem solved after run this command **`sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup`**

```
$ sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
$ VBoxManage --version
5.0.14r105127
```

Answer (score 9):

You can always use *modprobe* to add a kernel module. I solved the same problem on my server by doing:

```
[root@mageia5][/home/afk]# modprobe -a vboxdrv
```

Comment: In this case, it's mostly not a problem that the module hasn't been loaded. This error appears when you've installed another kernel (mostly as a package update) which doesn't contain the vboxdrv module yet. So you have to compile and install the module to that new kernel, with `sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup`. AFAIR nowadays this command is mentioned in the error message, instead of `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`.

Answer (score 8):

I found the following virtualbox dkms related packages:

- virtualbox-dkms
- virtualbox-guest-dkms

Did you install these packages?

Comment: I don't have these packages installed indeed.

Comment: This worked for me. After that I just did `vagrant up` to have it running.

Answer (score 3):

> WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no 
>    module
>            available for the current kernel (4.7.1-1-ARCH) or it failed to
>            load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
>            sudo
>
> /sbin/vboxconfig
>
> You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.

The fix for this for me was to install the linux-headers package

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a [known bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14723).
Running the following commands fixes the problem:

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
```

Unfortunately, you will have to run these commands after each reboot.

Comment: You shouldn't have to run those commands after each reboot, only for each newly installed kernel (probably from a package update) that doesn't include the vboxdrv module yet. `rcvboxdrv setup` compiles the module and sets it up with the currently running kernel.

Comment: I agree, we shouldn't have to run /sbin/vboxconfig after each reboot, but when I upgraded my system from 18.04 to 20.04 that is exactly the situation I find myself in now - with Virtualbox 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Problem. Was searching for the solution for days.
In the end it was EFI blocking some functionality. My solve was to

1. restart machine
2. enter bios
3. disable "secure boot" under "security" (your specific name of the config could vary depending on the machine and bios used, but should be similar)

Hope this could help some nomads seeking days for answers like myself.