# Oracle VM Virtual box error

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, xubuntu

I install oracle vm virtual box v 5.1.20. When i tried to start this i had an error

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing
/sbin/vboxconfig as root.
where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

I looking for same problems and found it [VirtualBox "Kernel driver not installed" error despite running /sbin/vboxconfig](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705720/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed-error-despite-running-sbin-vboxconfig) but when I run command `sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup` or `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig setup` I had this:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
```

After runnig `dpkg -l *virtualbox*`i got

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  virtualbox     <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  virtualbox-5.1 5.1.20-11462 amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
ii  virtualbox-dkm 5.0.36-dfsg- all          x86 virtualization solution - ker
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  virtualbox-gue 5.0.36-dfsg- all          x86 virtualization solution - gue
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  virtualbox-gue 5.0.36-dfsg- amd64        x86 virtualization solution - non
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-mod <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-ose <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Comment: Run `dmesg | tail -f` and post it

Comment: Is virtualization enabled in BIOS?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `dpkg -l *virtualbox*`.

Comment: after running `dmesg | tail -f` i got 
`[  125.877596] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[  165.660959] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[  187.269065] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[  267.519580] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[  287.253300] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
`

Comment: i fix it when i disabled secure boot into bios

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

If you get dependency errors do

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

After all dkms packages are correctly instaled do

```
sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

Comment: all dkms packages intalled, but i had the same problem

Comment: No change at all.