# VirtualBox giving "kernel driver not installed" error

Tags: virtualbox

I'm a complete newcomer to Linux, and I want to install a couple of distributions in VirtualBox so I can see what they're like. I've installed the program and followed various tutorials online but every time I try to create a machine I get the following error:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up
> correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing
>
> '/sbin/vboxconfig'
>
> as root.
>
> If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign
> the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before
> you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for
> more information.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The
> support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

I've tried entering "sudo /sbin/vboxconfig" into the terminal but that hasn't helped. This is a brand new installation of Ubuntu; I haven't messed around with anything. Any help would be appreciated, as well as recommendations for an orderly way to learn Linux instead of just mucking around on YouTube.

Comment: Also, in the future it would help to include the output of the `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` command to let us know why it didn't work. If the linked answer doesn't help, please let us know and please explain in full detail why and we'll try and get this figured out further.

Comment: If the other answer doesn't fix your problem: [according to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/705785/167115), you may have to run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-guest-dkms` and then reboot to apply the changes.

Comment: The suggested answer fixed the issue; thanks very much.